# Is there a way to alter the type returned by a compound requirement inside a concept?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I've been playing around with concepts, and came across something I'm not quite sure about. Take the following code ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Compound_Requirements) states that "`decltype((expression))` must satisfy the constraint imposed by the type-constraint"):

```
#include <concepts>

class Base { };
class Derived : public Base { };

template<typename T> concept C1 =
requires(T x) {
  {x} -> std::derived_from<Base>; // decltype ((x)) returns Derived &
};

// This fails with error 'Base' is not a base of 'Derived&'
static_assert (C1<Derived>);
```

[Code on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fw8jW3)

Is there a way to apply additional operations such as `std::remove_reference_t` on the type returned from `{x}`, or any expression which returns a reference? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested requirement to apply any type modifications you need to do prior to the concept check:

```
template<typename T> concept C1 =
requires(T x) {
    requires std::derived_from<std::remove_reference_t<decltype((x))>, Base>;
};
```

(Note that the double parentheses are required to mimic the behavior of `{x}` in the compound requirement.) You can replace `x` by any expression you would have in `{x}` otherwise.

This is also, mostly, what the compound expression does. [[expr.primreq.compound]/1.3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#req.compound-1.3.2) specifies that your concept in the question behaves like

```
template<typename T> concept C1 =
requires(T x) {
  x;
  requires std::derived_from<decltype((x)), Base>;
};
```

(I am not entirely sure why the repeated simple requirement is necessary according to the example in the referenced standard passage, but I am probably forgetting some special case.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new concept, pretty much like `std::derived_from` and having `std::remove_reference_t` applied to derived type

```
#include <concepts>

class Base { };
class Derived : public Base { };

template<typename D, typename B>
concept is_derived_from_remove_ref = std::derived_from<std::remove_reference_t<D>, B>;

template<typename T> concept C1 =
requires(T x) {
  typename std::is_base_of<Base, T>;

  {x} -> is_derived_from_remove_ref<Base>; // decltype ((x)) returns Derived &
};


static_assert (C1<Derived>);
```

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://godbolt.org/z/fw5fkH)

Comment: This looks like a sensible way to handle it should this situation arise for anyone (the technical specification doesn't seem to shed any light), thanks.